# Предлагаю объединить метки “поэзия" и "стихи"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Предлагаю объединить метки “поэзия" и "стихи".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделано. Только тогда для вопросов о стихосложении придется использовать метку [метрика](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) или [стихосложение](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%85%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).